# getMimeType function returns null for FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5

I am getting an error `finfo::finfo() expects parameter 2 to be a valid path, string given` and i have looked in Symfony [Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.2/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/MimeType/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.html) and it says that this function returns `The mime type or NULL, if none could be guessed`
 but i dont quiet understand why it can't find the mime type. 
My route

`Route::get(
    '/images/{file}', 
    'ImageController@getImage'
);`

my url is `www.example.com/image/logo.png`

**my ImageController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;


class ImageController extends Controller {

    public function getImage($filename) {

        $path = \Config::get('assets.images') . $filename;


        $file = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File($path);
        // Make a new response out of the contents of the file
        // Set the response status code to 200 OK
        $response = \Response::make(
            \File::get($path), 
            200
        );

        // Modify output's header.
        // Set the content type to the mime of the file.
        // In the case of a .jpeg this would be image/jpeg
        $response->header(
            'Content-type',
            $file->getMimeType()
        );
        // We return our image here.
        return $response;
    }

}
```

`$file->getMineType()` is the issue and when i `var_dump($file)` i get `object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File)[185]
  private 'pathName' (SplFileInfo) => string '/home/vagrant/Code/project/storage/assets/images/logo.png' (length=55)
  private 'fileName' (SplFileInf`

I am a little confused why the png file type is null and same goes for any other file types.

I have narrow the issue down that the error is coming from [FileBinaryMimeTypeGuesser](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/File/MimeType/FileinfoMimeTypeGuesser.php) i have no idea what `magicFile` is might to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check if your php.ini have fileinfo extension enabled in php.ini

You can try,If the same happens with all filetypes is very probable that the extension is disabled so :

```
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

And i needs to be activated so :

```
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
```

In linux i think is

```
extension=fileinfo.so
```

Read more about fileinfo in [PHP Fileinfo functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php)

Uncomment that line in your php.ini file, restart apache and test